# ActiveMQ NMS consumer not receiving message at certain scenarios in C#

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

ActiveMQ NMS consumer (C#) can't able to receive old messages: My C# program will be in a while loop operating on message received.

I'm establishing a NMS consumer connection each time when I need a message and operate on the message received.

The problem is whenever I start the program the messages posted after my programs 1st connection attempt, I can get them downloaded/consumed.

However, if no messages are flowing in and I have some old messages sitting before I establish 1st connection, those messages are not getting consumed. I used proper `connection.start()`. and I'm using consumer.receive(0) 0 - waittime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you call a consumer receive with no timeout you are running the risk of not getting a message and must be prepared for that.  The consumer doesn't query the broker for a message on a call to receive so if there hasn't been a message dispatched or it's still in flight then the receive will return null message.

Creating a new connection on each attempt to get a message is really an anti-pattern and you should consider using a long lived connection / consumer to avoid this situation more, although you can't completely mitigate this as you are doing a receive(0).

Comment: Thank you. As you said its not a good design to establish and disconnect connection for each message i try to change for permanent one. I resolved this by adding a 2 second wait as receive(2 second) and it worked. Its not really waiting for 2 full second whenever it gets message it returned. in case of no message it waits 2 second.

Answer (score 1):

NNS consumer example contains the following line:

```
// Consume a message
ITextMessage message = consumer.Receive() as ITextMessage;
```

When running this code it may look as if consumer is returning `null` (but it doesn't).

Problem here is that `consumer.Receive()` returns an `IMessage` which is not always of type `ITextMessage`. In my case it was returning `ActiveMQBytesMessage` which is completely different type, and converting it to `ITextMessage` in `as ITextMessage` returns null.

The following code would be more appropriate as an example:

```
// Consume a message
IMessage message = consumer.Receive();
```